# Unable to parse very long binary string to numeric type

Tags: java, string, java-8

Folks, I am trying to parse an extremely long binary String to its decimal equivalent, but its throwing the `NumberFormatException`.

```
String s = "1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111" +
        "1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111" +
        "1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111" +
        "1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111" +
        "1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111" +
        "1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111" +
        "1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111" +
        "1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111" +
        "1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111" +
        "1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111" +
        "1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111" +
        "1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111" +
        "1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111" +
        "1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111" +
        "111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111" +
        "1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111" +
        "1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111" +
        "1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111" +
        "1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111" +
        "1111111111111111"; //String length is 1969

long n = Long.parseLong(s, 2); //line no. 25

System.out.println(n);
```

But it's giving the below-mentioned Runtime error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1111[...]111"
> at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
> at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:592)
> at Check2.main(Check2.java:25)

Tried using BigInteger,valueOf() methods too, but all efforts are going in vain.

Please do let me know if there's any other way to achieve the desired result.

Comment: `new BigInteger(s, 2)`. Yields (see next comment).

Comment: 53464001755893906775528248454336169363107425257968492828199767359800928337144214373857690315530927382337207190645274835333559613715068219761640362263035643165525975239142905921064680045582374963643460995547234194717190909966075962384844676610299550914627032614388688844137186932202108041167335688122703079760153269853656415642415864769329344341966685140705203039900691169557165416067597126477057059908847603479119212425789693304525707922807514318982553404710298367103076439159769583102353828594382192359948728971055716056539111966002757898026740077828348230307702348019388863266429609508339711

Comment: This WORKED!! One more final help if you could pls provide  - I am trying to perform the below-mentioned operations but it's taking forever to compute it. Basically trying to compute the number of operations required to reduce that number n to 0, wherein the operations are :- Subract 1 if it's odd, divide by 2 if even, and finally return the count. That's it!!  Please see the edited question for the complete code

Comment: To generalize my coment from before: `n.bitLength()` gives you the total number of bits from the first one bit. Subtract one to get the number of times you need to divide by 2. `n.bitCount()` gives you the number of one bits, so the number of times you need to subtract 1. So add those two numbers for a count of operations.

Comment: Man, it worked!! FINALLY!! I think I have learned a LOT from the approach that you have provided, in solving this problem. I hardly knew about the various things(bitLength(), bitCount(), and tons of other in-build stuff this BigInteger provides) previously, at least as per the knowledge I have gained so far. I almost thought that it would be near impossible to perform such operations on such a big String in Java. Anyway, really appreciate your time and help on the same. - @OleV.V. : )

Comment: Sure, it was a pleasure, not least seeing that it actually helped. I regularly look through all of the methods of a class that i am using, no matter if I think I need one or not, but I tend to learn a lot from doing it. [Documentation of `BigInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigInteger.html).

Answer (score 2):

The java long data type has a minimum value of **-9,223,372,036,854,775,808** and a maximum value of **9,223,372,036,854,775,807**. The number you have is much greater than the maximum limit allowed.

You can use BigInteger for your String instead.

```
BigInteger result = new BigInteger(inputString, 2);
```

Comment: Absolutely right! But, is there STILL a way to perform the desired task and achieve the desired outcome?

Comment: what is the desired task? If you just add the string to new BigInteger, you can get the desired result

Comment: If somebody needs to work with floats, there is the BigDecimal ... same logic.

Comment: The author @AshishRamtri meantions that the string provided is in binary format (radix=2). The constructor of BigDecimal used in your answer uses decimal (radix=10) however, Thus my edit you rolled back ...

Comment: Oh, I realize my mistake now

Comment: This WORKED!! Thanks all! One more final help if you could all pls provide - I am trying to perform the below-mentioned operations but it's taking forever to compute it. Basically trying to compute the number of operations required to reduce that number n to 0, wherein the operations are :- Subtract 1 if it's odd, divide by 2 if even, and finally return the count. That's it!! Please see the edited question for the complete code. - @Everyone

Answer (score 2):

Both `int` and `long` have a maximum (and miminum) value, see the documentation for [int](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MAX_VALUE) and [long](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#MAX_VALUE) accordingly.
The decimal representation of your binary string exceeds these limits.

You might use a [BigDecimal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) instead to parse the String.
It provides a constructor accepting a String with the number and the radix to use. As your string is in binary format, you should pass the radix value of 2.

```java
BigInteger myValue = new BigInteger(s, 2);
```

Comment: This WORKED!! Thanks! One more final help if you could pls provide - I am trying to perform the below-mentioned operations but it's taking forever to compute it. Basically trying to compute the number of operations required to reduce that number n to 0, wherein the operations are :- Subract 1 if it's odd, divide by 2 if even, and finally return the count. That's it!! Please see the edited question for the complete code

Comment: I'm glad I could help. @AshishRamtri as this has nothing to do with your original problem (the parsing error) I would recommend asking a new question focussed on the new problem instead. And change this question back to the original core instead.

Comment: I'd have loved to change it back to the original core, but some others have already commented based on the latest post update. BUT, I'll definitely make sure that going forward I follow your advice on the same. Thanks again! : )

Comment: No worries. I still would consider adding this as a separate question so that others with the same or a similar problem might find a solution easier. Maybe notify Ole V. V. about it so that they may add their answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

An answer to the amendment:

If you want to calculate with `BigInteger` you have to do **all** operations with `BigInteger`. In the code fragment

```
    BigInteger n = new BigInteger(s, 2);
    int count = 0;
    while (n.intValue() != 0) {
        if (n.intValue() % 2 == 0) {
            n = BigInteger.valueOf(n.intValue() / 2);
            count++;    
        } else {
            n = BigInteger.valueOf(n.intValue() - 1);
            count++;
        }

    }
    System.out.println(count);
```

you loose important information every time you call `n.intValue()` and every time you create a new `BigInteger` from an `int` (actually a `long`, the public `BigInteger.valueOf()` only accepts a `long`.)

This is because an `int` can only store 32 bits, the value you start with however has 1969 bits. `n.intValue()` extracts the lowest 32 bits, and after `BigInteger.valueOf(n.intValue() - 1)` / `BigInteger.valueOf(n.intValue() / 2)` all but those last 32 bits are lost.

The code works if you replace it with

```
    BigInteger n = new BigInteger(s, 2);
    int count = 0;
    while (!n.equals(BigInteger.ZERO)) {
        count++;
        if (!n.testBit(0)) {
            n = n.divide(BigInteger.TWO);
        } else {
            n = n.subtract(BigInteger.ONE);
        }
    }
    return count;
```

---

Why does your code lead to an endless loop?

The endless loop arises from the fact that the `int` value that has all bits set is -1.

Your original loop produces these values:

1. -1 is odd, therefore it subtracts 1 which gives -2
2. -2 is even, the value is divided by 2 which gives -1

Comment: I was able to run your counting in less than 0.01 seconds on my old computer. Which is a pretty vast difference from “forever”. (Not upvoting since the question no longer asks about this.)

Comment: Thanks for providing a detailed explanation as to why my code didn't work and went into an endless loop. Also, I was able to implement something along the lines of your solution, except for the BigInteger.TWO - which I guess is not supported in Java 8 but from Java 9 onwards, and I am currently on Java8. Nevertheless, appreciate your help on the same. - @Thomas Kläger

Answer (score 1):

You can use this following method `BigInteger()` for integer conversion:

```
BigInteger bi = new BigInteger(inputstring, 2);
```

or you can use `BigDecimal()` like so:

```
BigDecimal bd1 = new BigDecimal(inputstring.charAt(0)=='1'?1:0);
BigDecimal two = new BigDecimal(2);
for (int i = 1; i<inputstring.length(); i++) {
    bd1 = bd1.multiply(two);
    bd1 = bd1.add(new BigDecimal(inputstring.charAt(i)=='1'?1:0));
}
System.out.println("Big decimal number is"+ bd1);
```

Comment: Same answer already added for the question

Comment: Thanks but you can use BigDecimal(). Which I mention second example.